# How to set severity based on the issue type for SonarLint for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I want to set Bugs and Vulnerabilities as errors and Code Smells as warnings for the SonarLint extension in Visual Studio. I prefer to set it generically, rather than right-clicking each issue and setting its severity. Is it possible for me to do that? If yes, please tell me how to do it.

Thanks and Regards,

Arjun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since specification for each rule is publicly available: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/tree/3ab2e10b4effa8760b3ecd4fbb2b3d59f43f1b7f/analyzers/rspec/cs, it was quite easy to write a program that would generate `.editorconfig` with all rules.

Here it is: https://github.com/Peska/SonarAnalyzersRules/blob/master/.editorconfig

Grouped by type - `CODE_SMELL`, `BUG`, `SECURITY_HOTSPOT`, `VULNERABILITY` - and ordered by `Severity` in case you want to change something in a future.

I cannot paste full `.editorconfig` as an answer it here, since there is 30k characters limit.